# Question: Optimizing SVG Animations for Different Screen Sizes

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, sass

Description: I'm working on a project that involves animating multiple SVGs on a web page. The project consists of three main components: JavaScript code, CSS styles, and HTML structure. These components work together to create responsive SVG animations that adapt to different screen sizes.

1. **JavaScript Code**: I have a JavaScript script that controls the animation of these SVGs based on the screen width. The code calculates the scroll position and updates the **`strokeDashoffset`** property of SVG path elements. While it works well on larger screens, I'm encountering issues on smaller screens. How can I optimize this script for better responsiveness, especially on smaller screens? You can see My approach is the same for evert screen. here's my entire script

```
let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
let isWidth1371 = false;
let isWidth769 = false;
let isWidth376 = false;
if (screenWidth > 1371) {

  setupScrollAnimation('svgAnimation', 'runningLine');
} else if (screenWidth < 1370 && screenWidth > 991) {
  isWidth1371 = true;
  isWidth769 = false;
  isWidth376 = false;
  setupScrollAnimation('svgAnimation1370', 'runningLine1370');
}
else if (screenWidth < 769 && screenWidth > 575) {
  isWidth1371 = false;
  isWidth769 = true;
  isWidth376 = false;
  setupScrollAnimation('svgAnimation768', 'runningLine768');
} else if (screenWidth < 376) {
  isWidth1371 = false;
  isWidth769 = false;
  isWidth376 = true;
  setupScrollAnimation('svgAnimation375', 'runningLine375');
}


function setupScrollAnimation(svgAnimationId, runningLineId) {
  let isLetSpread = false;
  let isNewArrival = false;
  let isLocations = false;
  let isKeyAssociation = false;
  let isOurStory = false;
  let isCounter = false;
  let isUpdates = false;

  const animation_path = document.getElementById(runningLineId);
  const animation_path_length = animation_path.getTotalLength();
  animation_path.style.strokeDasharray = animation_path_length + ' ' + animation_path_length;
  animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length;
  const parent_elem = document.getElementById(svgAnimationId).closest('.svg-animation-container');

  const svg_start_top = document.getElementById('counterSection').getBoundingClientRect().height;
  if (isWidth1371) {
    document.getElementById(svgAnimationId).style.top = (svg_start_top - 100) + 'px';

  }
  else if (isWidth769) {
    parent_elem.style.top = (svg_start_top - 125) + 'px';
  } else if (isWidth376) {
    parent_elem.style.top = (svg_start_top + 125) + 'px';

  }
  else {

    document.getElementById(svgAnimationId).style.top = svg_start_top + 'px';
  }


  const main = document.querySelector('main');
  const sections = main.querySelectorAll('section');


  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    let scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      let sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
      let sectionBottom = sectionTop + section.offsetHeight;



      if (section.id == 'counterSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isCounter = true;
        } else {
          isCounter = false;
        }
      }
      if (section.id == 'updatesSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isUpdates = true;
        } else {
          isUpdates = false;
        }
      }

      if (section.id == 'letsSpreadSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isLetSpread = true;
        } else {
          isLetSpread = false;
        }

      }
      if (section.id == 'newArrivalSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isNewArrival = true;
        } else {
          isNewArrival = false;
        }
      }

      if (section.id == 'locationsSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isLocations = true;
        } else {
          isLocations = false;
        }
      }
      if (section.id == 'keyAssociationsSection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isKeyAssociation = true;
        } else {
          isKeyAssociation = false;
        }
      }
      if (section.id == 'ourStorySection') {
        if ((this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) >= sectionTop && (this.document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) <= sectionBottom) {
          isOurStory = true;
        } else {
          isOurStory = false;
        }
      }

    });
    let drawLength;
    drawLength = animation_path_length * scrollPercentage;

    if (screenWidth > 768) {
      console.log('screenWidth greater than 768');
      if (isLetSpread || isNewArrival || isLocations || isKeyAssociation || isOurStory || isCounter || isUpdates) {
        if (isCounter) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 4000;
        }
        if (isUpdates) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 4000;
        }
        if (isLetSpread) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 1200;
        }

        if (isNewArrival) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 1800;
        }
        if (isLocations) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 3000;
        }
        if (isKeyAssociation) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 3000;
        }
        if (isOurStory) {
          animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength - 3000;
        }

      } else {

        animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - 1000;
      }
    }

    else {
      animation_path.style.strokeDashoffset = animation_path_length - drawLength;
      console.log('screenWidth 5 else');

    }

  });
}
```

My CSS (scss)

```
.svg-animation-container {
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1458px;
  margin: 0px auto;

  svg {
    position: absolute;
  }

  .svg-animation-1440 {
    display: none;
  }

  .svg-animation-1370 {
    display: none;
  }

  .svg-animation-768 {
    display: none;
  }

  .svg-animation-375 {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    svg {
      position: static;
    }

  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 567px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    .svg-animation-768 {
      display: block;
      min-width: 1207px;
      max-width: 1207px;

    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1371px) {
    .svg-animation-1440 {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 1370px) {


    .svg-animation-1370 {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @include mq(tablet) {



    .svg-animation-1370 {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  @include mq(phone) {
    .svg-animation-375 {
      display: block;
      min-width: 557px;
      max-width: 557px;
    }
  }


}
```

My HTML structure

```
 <main>
      <div class="svg-animation-container">
        <svg id="svgAnimation375" class="svg-animation-375" viewBox="0 0 557 5135" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <!--  ...... other paths  -->
          <path d="M295.498 138.5C294.165 1 ......"  stroke="#DFDFDF" stroke-width="1.3" >
            <path id="runningLine375"  d="M295.498 138.5C294.165 1 ......"  stroke="#1D1D1D" stroke-width="1.3"  > <!--this is a copy of above which we are animating -->
              <!--  ...... other paths  -->

        </svg>
        <svg id="svgAnimation768" class="svg-animation-768" viewBox="0 0 1207 6959" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <!-- ...... other paths  -->
          <path  stroke="#DFDFDF" stroke-width="1.3" >
            <path id="runningLine768"  stroke="#1D1D1D" stroke-width="1.3" > <!--this is a copy of above which we are animating -->
              <!-- ...... other paths  -->
        </svg>
        <svg id="svgAnimation1370" class="svg-animation-1370" viewBox="0 0 557 5135" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <!-- ...... other paths  -->
          <path  stroke="#DFDFDF" stroke-width="1.3" >
            <path id="runningLine1370"  stroke="#1D1D1D" stroke-width="1.3" > <!--this is a copy of above which we are animating -->
              <!-- ...... other paths  -->
        </svg>
        <svg id="svgAnimation1370" class="svg-animation-768" viewBox="0 0 1207 6959" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <!-- ...... other paths  -->
          <path  stroke="#DFDFDF" stroke-width="1.3" >
            <path id="runningLine768"  stroke="#1D1D1D" stroke-width="1.3" > <!--this is a copy of above which we are animating -->
              <!-- ...... other paths  -->
        </svg>
        <svg id="svgAnimation" class="svg-animation-1440" viewBox="0 0 1207 6959" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <!-- ...... other paths  -->
          <path  stroke="#DFDFDF" stroke-width="1.3" >
            <path id="runningLine"  stroke="#1D1D1D" stroke-width="1.3" > <!--this is a copy of above which we are animating -->
              <!-- ...... other paths  -->
        </svg>
      </div>
<section> </section>
<section> </section>
<section> </section>
<section> </section>
    </main>
```

I'm looking for guidance on why this is filling up in the middle instead of keeping the flow in responsive screens and performance of these SVG animations on different screen sizes. Any advice or suggestions on improving the JavaScript code, CSS styles, and HTML structure would be highly appreciated. I'm deeply focused on the RCA though, Thank you in advance for your expertise!